# Cannot access VirtualBox webserver on port 9000 from host OS

Tags: ubuntu, networking, windows-7, virtualization, virtualbox

I have a Ubuntu 12.04 guest VB on a W7 host. On the guest, I am running a webserver on port 9000 and can access that webserver from the guest on `127.0.0.1:9000`.

In VirtualBox, I have enabled two network adapters for the guest. I didn't change a setting for the first, so it's still NAT. The second adapter is a Host-Only-Adapter with default settings (VirtualBox 4.3.8).

`ifconfig` on the guest shows both `eth0` and `eth1`, where `eth1` has the IP address `192.168.56.101`, which I can successfully ping from the host. I can also successfully ping the host from the guest.

On the host, I get a "problem loading page" in FF for accessing `192.168.56.101:9000`. I checked with `nmap localhost` on the guest that 9000 is open: `9000/tcp open cslistener`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that the problem was not related to VB or anything, but to the server who only accepted requests from 127.0.0.1.